# "Source not found" message in Eclipse with JBoss at debug mode - breakpoint is in MY CODE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss, breakpoints

I started up JBoss in debug mode, my project is built by Maven, I work with Eclipse, the only breakpoint is in **my code**. But when I run the app it stops on a window with a name as the class I've put the breakpoint in, but it only shows the "Source not found."

What is it supposed to mean in my case, and how could I overcome this?

I am not an expert in debugging with Eclipse so I would appreciate a thorough explanation!

Comment: It is a case that the java files are in a different project and you have added a jar file of the project that you are currently debugging?

Comment: No, the the class I am trying to debug is in the current project. Not a dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have configured your Debug settings for a particular project in your workspace(in eclipse) which is deployed in JBOSS as jar or war, if the breakpoint is inside code that may be inside some other project(jar, war) which may be a dependency of the project for which you configured your debug settings then eclipse would not be able to find the source code. this is why you need to 'edit source look up' to the source code containing the source

Comment: The answer below tells you exactly how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9206318/295797

Answer (score 6):

Just Below **Source not found** error you will see "**Edit Source Lookup Path**" button click on it and then click on Add button then Java Project and include your imported project .. Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

There should be a button 'Edit Source Lookup Path' where you can add the location of you source files (where you put the breakpoint).

Comment: Thank you - could you please explain why eclipse/JBoss(?) could not figure out by itself where the root of my java classes is. I thought eclipse could conclude it from my project's directory structure?

Comment: @rapt I really don't know why it can't infer that. Anyway, I usually choose all my projects in the first debug, so I will never worry again with souce lookup. Austin gave a good explanation of why it asks for souce location.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your file system folder of the project in the JBoss server configuration:

> Servers (tab) -> Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.4 (right clic) -> Open (option) -> Open launch configuration -> Source -> Add -> File system directory (select your project folder) + Search subdirectories.